# User.Identity has values even with brand new start

Tags: .net, authentication, webforms, authorization

Even when I close my app and reopen it
even without me logging in I get username still exist and authenticated

```
{System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity}
[System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity]: {System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity}
AuthenticationType: "Forms"
IsAuthenticated: true
Name: "abc"
```

this is in my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

This is the login code

```
          if (ValidateUser(txtUserID.Text, txtUserPassword.Text))
              FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserID.Text, false);

          else
              lblMsg.Text = "Incorrect";
```

how to stop that?
i want the user to login everytime they want to access the app.

Comment: Are you setting the persistence to false on the ticket/cookie?

Comment: It is False, I updated my question with related code

Comment: What do you mean by closing the app? Closing the browser tab or window?

Comment: restarting the web application and closing the browser